# Can sufficient high degree polynomial sequences contain infinitely many primes?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have a conjecture:

For any integer $N$, there exist an positive integer $n > N$ such that there exist a degree-$n$ polynomial $P(x)$ satisfying:the sequence $\left\{P(n) \right\}$ contains infinitely many primes.

The conjecture came to me when I was trying to solve a problem concerning irreducible polynomials and prime numbers. This seems reasonable since we have a known result for degree-$1$ polynomials(Dirichlet's theorem). Furthermore, we can show that the sequence $\left\{n^2 + 1 \right\}$ contains infinitely many square-free integers by easy sift-method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the [Bunyakovsky Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture)

Comment: What does $N$ has to do with this?

Comment: It is conjectured that a polynomial produces infinite many primes , unless there is a common factor for each argument $x$ , but only for degree $1$ it has been proven.

Comment: @user10354138, the OP probably intends to require $n\gt N$.

Comment: In particular, the important case $n^2+1$ is open.

Comment: @Peter I believe *every* particular case (important or not) is open... no polynomial of degree $> 1$ has been proven to produce infinitely many primes, correct?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes, this is correct.

Comment: This is much weaker than the mentioned conjectures but I don't think there is a proof of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That conjecture is a consequence of "Schinzel's hypothesis H".
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H).

In particular, Schinzel's hypothesis H implies that any irreducible polynomial $f$ for which $f(n)$ is not always divisible by a fixed positive integer, is prime infinitely often.

The condition "not always divisible" takes care of $f(x)=x^N + x + 2$, for which $f(n)$ is always even.

It is possible I misunderstood the question because it was unclear what quantifiers you intended on $n$ and $P$.  If $P=P_n$ is supposed to have degree $n$, then what you wrote should still follow from standard conjectures, but perhaps not as trivially.